# JSON schema: how to allow empty string for property with numeric type?

Tags: php, json, jsonschema

In the property definition i need to allow numeric or empty string value, is this expression right for this purpose?

```
"tprice":{"type":["number",{"enum":[""]}]}
```

Library, that i use to validate data (Jsv4) generates error for empty string:

```
Invalid type: string
```

while i try to set zero length string for this property.

Answer (score 16):

I think the solution for you is the use of `anyOf` in the schema. 
This is the schema that works for you:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "properties": {
      "tprice": {
          "anyOf": [ 
          { 
              "type": "number"
          }, 
          { 
              "type": "string", 
              "maxLength": 0
          } 
       ] 
     }
  }
}
```

I've used [jsonschemalint.com](http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/#) to test it.

```
{
   "tprice": 123
}
```

and

```
{
   "tprice": ""
}
```

validates just fine.

Comment: Thank you, my expression were applicable for draft3, my validator is for draft4 and my data is php $_POST array, there is all strings, i think, i should use "string" type with pattern.

Comment: @vitus i think i don't understand you... did it work for you?